# Deleting records in SQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I use a string comparison on the date format to delete records on my database. I want to delete the past 5 minutes data. 
Here's the code that I am using. It seems to be not working. It does not delete any records. Why ?

```
     int rangeInMinutes = -5;
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar range = Calendar.getInstance();

                range.add(Calendar.MINUTE, rangeInMinutes);

  queryString.append(range);
 StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("date("'"+now +"'") > date("'"+range+"'");
int c = mydatabase.delete("mytable",  queryString.toString(), null)
```

The logcat shows: 0 record is deleted...

- I store the dates in a String format.

**UPDATE:**

After converting the date field from Text to Long in SQLite.

```
myddatabase.delete("mytable", "date > datetime('now','-5 minutes') AND date < datetime('now') ", null);
```

Still It does not delete any records. Why ?

Comment: In your code you use rangeInDays not rangeInMinutes, in the range.add is that correct?

Comment: `I store the dates in a String format.` Why not use the system unit of milliseconds and store as integer?  It will make comparisons much easier.

Comment: Sorry, It is a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @Simon, if i do not find a solution, i will do that. But, what is wrong with the code that I uploaded ?

Comment: Is date considered a reserved word? try [date] in comparisons

Comment: @basdwarf, date is the name of my column. I tried but it does not change anything.

Comment: To be frank, I'm not even going to work out what is wrong since it is a bad way of storing and comparing dates.  Make the change now before you get too far into your app ;)

Comment: Really, just do it now. I've been here many times. You realise that a design decision was wrong and you can't face correcting it but the return on the investment of fixing it pays back many times. You will end up with less code which is easier to read, more robust, higher performance and easier to maintain. What's not to like? The only place you should be doing this kind of manipulation is where (if) you show it to the user.  You've already wasted time pursuing this question which you could spend doing it properly.  Just do it, you won't regret it ;)  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Simon for your advice. The thing I am considering is that after storing integer, i will need to convert the date to string again and again. So, I am mixed up...

Comment: You don't need to convert it to string *except* when you show it to the user.  If you use milliseconds, you can do things like `if(date1 < date2)` and `WHERE thisDate => thatDate`.  Please explain why you think you need to convert to string again and again.

Comment: Yes, I will show it to the user. Anyway, I have started converting... Should I use int or long for it?

Comment: @Simon, I converted the date field from text to int. however, still I am not able to delete the records... Could you please help me ?

Comment: This question is getting too messy.  Start a new one, with your new code.  The important things to show are the new query, and how you set the values.  To answer your other question, you will need to handle milliseconds as long in your code, and integer in SQLite.  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java_android_date-and-time/

Comment: I updated it with the query that i used to delete, can you check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [sqlite date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Try this:

```
myddatabase.delete("mytable", "dateCol > datetime('now','-5 minutes') AND dateCol < datetime('now') ", null);
```

where dateCol is the name of your date column

**Edit:**

Here is the output for testing the where clause above:

```
 sqlite> create table test (_id int, testdate string);
create table test (_id int, testdate string);
sqlite> insert into test values(1, datetime('now'));
insert into test values(1, datetime('now'));
sqlite> insert into test values(2, datetime('now'));
insert into test values(2, datetime('now'));
sqlite> insert into test values(3, datetime('now'));
insert into test values(3, datetime('now'));
sqlite> insert into test values(4, datetime('now', '-10 minutes'));
insert into test values(4, datetime('now', '-10 minutes'));
sqlite> select * from test;
select * from test;
1|2013-07-25 21:01:05
2|2013-07-25 21:01:07
3|2013-07-25 21:01:09
4|2013-07-25 20:51:12
sqlite> select * from test where testdate < datetime('now') and testdate > datet
ime('now', '-5 minutes');
select * from test where testdate < datetime('now') and testdate > datetime('now
', '-5 minutes');
1|2013-07-25 21:01:05
2|2013-07-25 21:01:07
3|2013-07-25 21:01:09
sqlite> delete from test where testdate < datetime('now') and testdate > datetim
e('now', '-5 minutes');
delete from test where testdate < datetime('now') and testdate > datetime('now',
 '-5 minutes');
sqlite> select * from test;
select * from test;
4|2013-07-25 20:51:12
sqlite>
```

row with `_id 4` is excluded from the delete as it 10 minutes in the past and therefore is the only remaining row.

Comment: it gives an error: The method delete(String, String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

Comment: Sorry the last parameter should be an String Array, I am not near my java IDE at the moment

Comment: You could just set the last parameter to `null` and replace the `?` with `-5`

Comment: it is ok, What about 'now', is it recognized by sqlite or i define it?

Comment: I have updated it to `datetime('now')` after checking the documentation I linked, again. Have a look at it, it explains in detail. It basically returns the current date time.

Comment: Error again: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2cacf8

Comment: I think the error is related to the binding of the parameters, I have updated the answer to hardcode the parameter. If this doesn't work I will have spend more time testing. I just tested this in my project but I use [Cupboard](https://bitbucket.org/qbusict/cupboard) and it worked.

Comment: Now, no error but It does not delete any records just like my code. I think i should use integer date field for convenience, What do you think?

Comment: I would suggest one last thing to try: use the [SQLite3](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html) from the shell and do the delete using the sql syntax. It will allow you to play with the where clause and make sure the data is good (do selects to check the data is there to delete)

Comment: Thanks men, your approach helped me to find out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it appears to you are attempting to perform a math operation on a string - which will not result in what you think it will - thus your current predicament.

You would be much better off on almost every aspect of what you are trying to accomplish using time in milliseconds: performance, simplicity and allow the native db engine to do the work for you.  By storing as a string, you prevent the db engine from doing any sort of compare that you would normally do with dates.  Second, storing as a string is a terrible waste of space, which Android has a limited amount of on the phone to begin with.

You will need a **long** not an integer if you work with the time value in code - you will surely overflow your buffer if you try to push a time value in milliseconds into an integer.

Comment: I was right in every respect ;) SQLite stores numerics very differently.  It does not have a long data type.  It will store a long as an integer of 8 bytes. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @Simon, sorry I was referring to the Java datatypes, not sqlite.